# Example of Ant Design Table with both resizable columns and drag and drop columns?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to implement both resizable and drag and drop columns in [Ant Design's Table component](https://ant.design/components/table/).

I have got both working independently but cannot make them work without errors or bugs at the same time. I need to be able to drag on a column border and resize it horizontally and also be able to click on a the column header and drag and drop it.

I am looking for these functionalities to be similar to the features of this table:
https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php

I have tried implementing it with [react-resizable](https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable) for resizable columns and both [react-sortable-hoc](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc) and [react-drag-listview](https://github.com/raisezhang/react-drag-listview) for drag and dropping column order.

With the react-drag-listview the latest problem is that I must disable one feature when using the other, and in Firefox, this results in the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: target.parentNode

I can't find any examples of both of these features being used together with the Ant D table but I'm sure it must be possible to make them work simultaneously.

TIA

Comment: I guess they've removed the feature that allows columns to be resizable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start it with antd table resizable column codes from documentation then you can integrate the [react-drag-listview](https://github.com/raisezhang/react-drag-listview) library to make the columns draggable. With these, you can achieved a resizable columns at the same time can be sort by drag and drop. See below link for reference.

[Table column drag and drop sortable and resizable](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-column-sortable-resizable-st9bt)

Comment: Thank you, thanks a great example and one I couldn't find anywhere else!

Comment: After some more playing around with this and whilst it is a solution, there is a problem with it. In your example, go the the 'Gender' column and resize it so it is as big as it can go and the mouse is directly over 'Age'. Then lift the mouse key up. Click on Age with the mouse to select it and drag it. When you drag you will see that it does not drag the column header cell but only the text.

Comment: I tried what you said (i tried it also in full window) but its working on me.. maybe you can ask another question regarding on this and also include some gif image demo of what is happening so me and others can debug it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok thanks I'm going to do this as would be great to get solved. I'm going to mark the question as the answer as you provided a working example.

Comment: Thanks! Happy coding :)